# Parent never calls for wait function , still zombie not created

Tags: unix

**"Parent never calls for wait function , still zombie process is not created "**
can anyone explain this with example ! thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ignore your children (`SIG_IGN` the `SIGCHLD` signal), you don't have to wait for them. You can also explicitly not wait for them via the `SA_NOCLDWAIT` flag for `sigaction()`.